# angular-generator-fullstack in ionic with login facebook

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, passport-facebook

I have a problem with angular-fullstack-generator and I don’t know resolve. I have an app online at a specific address: www.example.com, I have also an hybrid app, created with ionic, that runs in local, not external webview!

The problem is logical. I have same source for web app and hybrid app.
When I click login button in my ionic app, the button opens a location.href to address web "$window.location.href = '/auth/' + provider", that in my hybrid app will be file://blabla/auth/blabla and it doesn’t work. So I used inappbrowser and I open www.example.com/auth/blabla, the user can do login , but the endpoint /auth/blabla will return a cookie in www.example.com, and this is the problem.

In nodejs I have:

```
export function setTokenCookie(req, res) {
if (!req.user) {
return res.status(404).send('It looks like you aren\'t logged in, please try again.');
}
var token = signToken(req.user._id, req.user.role);
res.cookie('token', token);
res.redirect('/');
}
```

The problem is this redirect will go www.example.com, how can I handle it ? In Ionic I don’t have a server web, and I would not change login method because the app site is online.
Help me, please.